# Update object after function return

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a simple Api consume service with JavaScript. This service has a 3 properties (loading, data, error) and I want to change thats properties values dynamicly in promise and I want to use this service like that ->

```
const { loading, data, err } = new ApiService().send(request).getResults();
```

My main goal is dynamic loading and data so during Api call loading property's value equals to true and when Api call finished loading property's value equals to false and data property filled with Api response. So I want to use this service like that ->

```
  const { loading, data, err } = new ApiService().setSync(false).send(q).getResults();
  if (loading) {
     pElement.text("Loading");
  } else {
     pElement.text(data.id);
  }
```

My Api service codes:

```
function ApiService(header = {}) {
    this._loading = false;
    this._data = {};
    this._header = header;
    this._error = "";
    this._isAsync = false;
}

ApiService.prototype.setSync = function (isAsync = false) {
    this._isAsync = isAsync;
    return this;
};

ApiService.prototype.send = function (request) {
    const self = this;
    if (!this._isAsync) {
      this._loading = true;
      request
      .then(function (data) {
          self._loading = false;
          self._data = data;
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
          self._error = e;
      });

      return this;
      } else {
          return request
                 .then(function (data) {
                      self._loading = false;
                      self._data = data;
                      return data;
                   })
                   .catch(function (e) {
                      self._error = e;
                   });
      }
 };

 ApiService.prototype.getResults = function () {
     const self = this;
     return { loading: self._loading, data: self._data, err: self._error };
 };

 module.exports = ApiService;
```

This service works once and its returns default values as normaly but I want to dynamic update values. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: **No**. After a return statement you cant update the values like you have in mind.

Frameworks like React.js do have syntax like this in their Hooks API, but they also have components which are executed again every time a state changes, resulting in having the variables re-evaluated.

In Vanilla JS land the easiest thing to do is to return a Promise, wait for it to finish and then continue. I think that using `async / await` is the closest thing to making your code behaving as you would like.

The snippet below demonstrates how that would look and run. The returned `loading` value would always be `false` as you would only get the result after it's done loading, so it can be omitted.

```
function ApiService(header = {}) {
    this._loading = false;
    this._data = {};
    this._header = header;
    this._error = "";
    this._isAsync = false;
}
  
ApiService.prototype.send = async function(request) {
  this._loading = true;
  this._data = {};
  this._error = "";
  try {
    const data = await request();
    this._data = data;
  } catch(error) {
    this._error = error;
  } finally {
    this._loading = false;
    return { 
      data: this._data, 
      error: this._error, 
    };
  }
}
```

```
(async () => {
  pElement.text("Loading");
  const { data, err } = await new ApiService().send(request);
  if (!err) {
    pElement.text(data.id);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know how to do this in React context but I want to do this in vanilla JavaScript but as I understand it, I have to make a wrapper to render the function again. So I give up for that feature because I can't maintain that wrapper.